# VBA GoTo function - find date

Tags: excel, vba

I have 12 sheets named by months, the dates are in row A (eg: sheet "Jun" cell "A1" is 1.1.2021, "B1" is 2.1.20201 and so on). I want my code to go to cell inside a sheet that contains today's date (eg.: if i run my code on 5th June, it should open sheet "Jun" cell "E1").

How can i make it work to properly check whole workbook and go to today's date?

I tried using Arrays (method2 but is not working) since my code now only works for one month, but does not check every sheet and works only by days in month, not the whole dates, as can be seen from code:

```
Sub TOday() 
X = Day(Date)

Worksheets("Jun").Select 'Method1
Worksheets("Jun").Rows(1).Find(What:=X, LookIn:=xlValues).Activate 'Method1



'Worksheets(Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Maj", "Jun", "Jul", "Avg", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec")).Select --> Method2
'Worksheets(Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Maj", "Jun", "Jul", "Avg", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec")).Rows(1).Find(What:=X, LookIn:=xlValues).Activate --> Method2


Application.Goto Selection, True

End Sub
```

Comment: Are your worksheets in order and only the 12 sheets in the workbook?

Comment: If so use: `Worksheets(Month(Date)).Activate` and `ActiveSheet.Cells(1,Day(Date)).Select`

Comment: @ScottCraner: Or `MonthName(month(Date))`, or `left(MonthName(month(Date)),3)`

Comment: oh no, I should have typed `format(date,"MMM")`